# Stumped on Xamarin databinding cast exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I've followed examples and worked with XAML for WPF and this never happens so I'm totally confused about why Xamarin Forms is complaining.

Here's a simple form where I'm trying to use a ListView. The general structure is what was generated by Visual Studio but I've put in the ListView with an template for drawing two Labels:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PrivateDiary.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PrivateDiary.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView x:Name="AboutListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Detail}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace PrivateDiary.Views
{
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AboutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

and my View Model:

```
namespace PrivateDiary.ViewModels
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AboutItem> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<AboutItem>();
        public AboutViewModel()
        {
            Title = "About";

            Items.Add(new AboutItem {Name = "Version", Detail = "0.3"});
            Items.Add(new AboutItem {Name = "Privacy Policy", Detail = "#privacy"});

        }
        
    }

    public class AboutItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }

    }
}
```

BaseViewModel is the stock one generated by Visual Studio 2019 (16.10.3) so I won't list it here. It implements the details for INotifyPropertyChanged, a page Title property and IsBusy property.
When I run the app I get this:
[image]

If I removed the Items.Add(...) lines there's no problems.

Any ideas why it fails to cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add element `ViewCell` outside of element `Grid` in your xaml

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <listviewapp1:AboutViewModel></listviewapp1:AboutViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView x:Name="AboutListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
<!--add ViewCell here-->
                    <ViewCell>  
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Detail}" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```